# Using IMPORTXML to scrape content from web pages

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I’m trying to use IMPORTXML to pull job information from Linkedin into Google sheets. I have a list of job URLs which I hope to pull various elements from the page (job title, description, company profile link etc.) into a spreadsheet. No matter what I try, I can’t get it to pull anything.

As far as I can see, the below formula looks correct but it returns a “Could not fetch URL” error

```
=IMPORTXML("www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/585970109","//*[@id='job-details'])")
```

Any ideas of what I’m doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will give tip may helps you. inside IMPORTHTML() built-in function it use urlFetching so it get results of the page without Compiling JavaScript because it just Http request who compile JavaScript is the browser. if you go to Linkedin site settings and disable JavaScript and reload, Data in page won't appear and most of sites do that to protect their data from that things.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see what you mean. So does that mean it's impossible to pull that content from Linkedin?